# Mockito - MockSettings with spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, mockito

I'm trying to setup mocked object (using `Mockito`) via spring bean configuration, however I don't know how to setup `MockSettings` for that object. Especially I would like to set up object serializable.

Programatically it is possible by:

```java
Object serializableMock = mock(Object.class, withSettings().serializable());
```

```xml
<bean id="object" name="object" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="object" />
    <constructor-arg value="org.mockito.MockSettings"> ???  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Can somebody guide me how to do that ? Thanks in advance

BTW : I want to use pure XML configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Only via XML, you can't.

Actually I wouldn't recommend you to have the usual practice of using Mockito mocks in spring for tests. Here's why :

- Usually when **Unit Testing**, you want to test **one** class in isolation, it's unit testing after all, so Spring DI isn't necessary at all in this case. You just inject the collaborators of your test subject yourself or maybe via the handy [`@InjectMock`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) annotation.
- If however you need to test things with another system like a DAO with a Database, then indeed you probably need Spring wiring to connect to either the real DB or some in memory DB like H2. But in this case you are crafting an **Integration Test**. And you most probably don't need mocks in this case.

That said, you might have specific needs and the above point could be irrelevant in your **specific bounded context**. But then again, in my opinion if it's specific I don't think it's overkill to craft yourself a simple MockSettings [factory bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AbstractFactoryBean.html) (that could even be configurable).

E.g. you could write this once and for all in a technical module of your application :

```
public class SpringMockSettingsFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<MockSettings> {
    @Override public Class<Multimap> getObjectType() {
        return MockSettings.class;
    }

    @Override protected Multimap<String, String> createInstance() throws Exception {
        // ... your code

        return mockSettings;
    }
}
```

There's a project [springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) on bitbucket that tries to have a mockito focused namespace in spring. I don't think the project can do that, but the framework's author might be interested to implement the feature.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do it via XML

```
   <bean id="mockSettings" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="withSettings" init-     method="verboseLogging">

    </bean>
    <bean id="sqsHelper" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="com.elsevier.vtw.aws.helper.SQSHelper"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="mockSettings" />

    </bean>
```

Comment: heads up! this worked for me with mockito 1.9 and spring 3.1.1